# How many WinForm event message are in queue?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have created an event in a BackgroundWorker to send text notifications to a WinForm Panel. After the BachgroundWorker is finished I change the Panel and start the next BackgroundWorker.
My Problem is that when the BGW is finished not all event messages are arrived in my Panel. 
Bevor removing the Panel I want to process all event messages.
How can I observe or check if there are more event messages in queue?

thanks for your help

Comment: Put some code here, please

Comment: We cannot offer any assistance whatsoever without seeing the relevant code. The problem you're having could be caused by any number of things and without seeing how you're attempting it, we can't even begin to guess what's wrong.

Comment: Application.DoEvents().  In general about as bad an idea as looking for this band-aid and ignore the real problem.  Don't fire-hose the UI thread in your worker.

Comment: Thanks for your answers

Comment: I have made a code example and guess what? Everything is working fine. So it really looks like I have an other problem in my real application. Just like you were telling me.

Answer (score -2):

PeekMessage is your friend. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943(v=vs.85).aspx for description

Comment: I think this should be comment not answer

Comment: Just as detailed as the question